# Ajax Control Toolkit, Visual Studio 2013, Nuget: AjaxControlToolkit.dll is missing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, nuget, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I tried to add the actual `Ajax Control Toolkit` to an `.Net 4.5.1` WebSite. All the dependencies seem to be properly installed but the `AjaxControlToolkit.dll` file is not there.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the package with the `NuGet Console` in `Visual Studio 2013` and it always looks to be successful, but also always that dll is missing. Also restarting VS did not help.
In the `packages.config` the entry for the dll with version 8.0.0.0 is there and also in the `packages` directory there a directory `AjaxControlToolkit.8.0.0.0.` but only the `AjaxControlToolkit.8.0.0.0.nupkg` and the `readme.txt` files are there.

Any idea, what went wrong or what I could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start a command prompt and run `dir c:\ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll /s` to see if the file is somewhere on your system.  If it is, then copy it to the project's bin folder.

If it's not on your hard drive, go to http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/116091, download the version in question, and copy the .dll from the package to the project's bin folder.

In the back of my mind it seems that I ran into this a couple of weeks ago, also, so there may be a bug in NuGet.

Comment: @afj if this worked, please accept this as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Tony, thank you that worked for me (with v15.1).
But it's a workaround and not a solution, a solution would be a working NuGet package.

Comment: It is probably a bug with NuGet since I had the same problem, and if that's the case you'll need to get whoever maintains NuGet to fix it.  I just looked through the "known issues" list, which seems rather short (i.e., I doubt that it really shows all known issues).  You can report NuGet issues at https://www.codeplex.com/site/login?RedirectUrl=https%3a%2f%2fnuget.codeplex.com%2fWorkItem%2fCreate%3fProjectName%3dnuget.

Answer (score 0):

Version 8.0.0.0 of the NuGet package is broken.

Update [15.1.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit/15.1.2) is available.

P.S. Dependencies are extracted into separate packages ([AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer/), [AjaxControlToolkit.StaticResources](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit.StaticResources/))